# I Can't Opening A Txt File In Program Of C Language

Tags: c, fopen

I have my code here.  Every time I try to open a text file it's giving me an error message.

```
Person temp;
FILE *in, *out;
in = fopen_s(&in,"the_first.txt","rt");
if (!in)
   Error_Msg("Error message");
fscanf_s(in,"%d",&temp.ID);
fclose(in);
_getch();
return 0;
```

What do I need to change in my code to make it work?

Comment: `errno_t err;`.. `err = fopen_s(&in,"the_first.txt","rt"); if (err)`

Comment: Does the file exist in the current directory where the program is executing? And check err, as BluePix suggests to learn what the actual error is.

Comment: Please post the error here by calling strerror(errno);

Comment: As BLUEPIXY suggests, the error is that the return value of fopen_s is an error code and should not be assigned to `in`.

Comment: I Don't Have An Error Its Just Not Open To Me The Txt ...
The Txt File Is Inside The Folder When The Code Is Written

Comment: You might like to RTFM here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Person temp;
FILE *in, *out;
errno_t err;

err = fopen_s(&in,"the_first.txt","rt"); 
if (err)
{
   Error_Msg("Error message");
}
else
{
    fscanf_s(in,"%d",&temp.ID);
    fclose(in);
    _getch();
}
return 0;
```